# no multithreading benefit with single core

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system

I'm new to concurrrent programming and multithreading. 
I can understand the benefits of multithreading with multicore processors, but does those benefit exist on single core processor,

For example, let's say we have a multicore computer and  a program to sum up a very large number as:

```
int sum = 0;
for (i=1, i<9999999999, i++)
{
   sum += i;
}

doOtherStuff();  // execute other function that is irrelevant to sum
...
...
//and then finally print the sum
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

so for the long running sum task, we can create a second thread to calculate the sum and the main thread keeps executing other functions.

But if we run this program on a single core computer, there is no benefits to create multithreads, isn't it? it is even worse with multithreads because of the context switches?

Answer (score 2):

There are two primary benefits to multi-threading.

1. It allows non-sequential computations to happen simultaneously,
   improving execution speed.
2. It also allows a program to not stall while waiting on blocking
   operations.

In your example, there is no increase in execution speed, because the processor must still execute each of the commands in one core. However, if you were waiting for user input during the loop (or performing another blocking application), you would be unable to complete doOtherStuff() if it is in the same thread. By keeping doOtherStuff() and its blocking operations in a separate thread, you would not hold up the execution of the sum operation.

In order to keep multiple applications running with a single core processor, the operating system uses round-robin execution. It moves from one thread/application to another executing a few lines at a time. By separating blocking situations into different threads, you can take advantage of this. This is commonly done with i/o operations.

Now, "is it worse?"

If you are memory constrained, there may be concerns because each thread carries its own stack. However, since the operating system is **already** switching context between various applications and operations, the downside to execution time by adding to the round-robin is likely to be small.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jeremy answer, (all correct), there is:

Multithreaded designs often allow the same software to take advantage of extra cores, when available, without rebuilds.

Multiple threads can allow execution-independent subsystems to be built that can be added to other apps with negligible effort or impact.

Many designs lend themselves naturally to multiple threads, the alternative of explicit, user-level state machines being complex and messy.